# Filtering using LINQ to SQL

Tags: .net, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have one table as below

```
ID Code  
1  9198  
2  9194  
3  91989  
4  91900  
5  918907
```

I have this table ready now what i want to do is that
like i have one value 919898989898 and from this value i get the below result from the table

```
Result  
ID Code  
1  9198
```

and if i pass 91989000155363 then result should be

```
Result  
ID Code  
3  91989
```

i want this kind of query in linq to sql that will match maximum char of given value match with database table.

Comment: So you want an analog of `Code.StartsWith(x)` in C#, or `Code LIKE '%' + x` in SQL?

Comment: Remember that any LINQ to SQL call should be **translatable** to SQL, otherwise you will need to load all the data into memory and process it by LINQ to Objects

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that code is actually a VARCHAR, you could try:

```
var input = "919898989898";
var allMatches = from item in dbContext
                 where input.StartsWith(item.Code)
                 orderby item.Code.Length descending
                 select item;
var longestMatch = allMatches.FirstOrDefault();
```

Or putting the query into a single statement, using dot notation instead of query expressions:

```
var longestMatch = dbContext.Where(item => input.StartsWith(item.Code))
                            .OrderByDescending(item => item.Code.Length)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now those queries are okay *logically* - but you'll have to try them to see whether they're correctly translated to SQL.

Comment: i tried that and get the below error. Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the String.StartsWith method.

Comment: @Ronak: In that case I'm not even sure it can be done in LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query = from item in dbContext
     where item.Code == input.Substring(0, item.Code.Length)
     orderby item.Code.Length descending
     select item;

var longestMatch = query.FirstOrDefault();
```